# Mysql select top n rows whilte count x<y

Tags: mysql, select, count, while-loop

I have a table with a column called `itemCount` and I want to select top n rows while `SUM(itemCount)` is less than `y` .

```
+----+-----------+
| id | itemCount |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         5 |
|  2 |        10 |
|  3 |         1 |
|  4 |        20 |
+----+-----------+
```

lets say `y=15` so in this case I want top 2 rows where `SUM(itemCount)<=15`
I need something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_mail_queue` LIMIT 0,(select count(id) from `tbl_mail_queue` m where SUM(m.`count`)<=15)
```

Is this possible?

UPDATE:

I am creating an email queue system where every email sent by my system gets stored in this table.Each email can have multiple recipients and I don't want to break them down to 1 recipient per each email row ( one of the modules whom sends email is newsletter which each mail can have dozens or even hundreds of recipients which I only break them into 50 recipient stacks) so in my emails table I have a column which tells me how many recipients that email have.

SO every row's count column can have a value from 1 to 50 , now I want to send 50 email every few minutes, here is where I need this query to select top 50 email which can be contained in 1 or more(n) rows.

Comment: i cant understand the question. Instead of specifying the query, you could express your requirement in words. You want SUM so its clear that you want to group by but by what parameter?

Comment: are you looking for `having (sum) <= 15`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is:

```
SELECT 
   test.id,
   test.itemCount 
FROM 
   test 
     LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT 
         id, 
         @sum:=@sum+itemCount AS current_sum 
        FROM 
          test 
          CROSS JOIN(SELECT @sum:=0) AS init) AS sums 
     ON test.id=sums.id 
WHERE sums.current_sum<=15;
```